# macro works on 2007 and later but not on 2003 (remove duplicates). What I have to do to make it work on 2003

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, excel-2003, excel-2010

Can anyone please help me. I have developed macro that keeps track of huge amount of data (note developed in excel 2007 vba) that deletes the duplicate entries with some userform options.

Let me explain my work I have 20 columns and 15000 rows ( might be increasing everymonth).
I have to delete the duplicate rows that are added every month.and The row is said to be duplicate if minimun 6 columns(out of 20) are Same.You dont need to check all 20 cloumns values in row but only 6 column values if those 6 columns value of 2 rows are same then you should eliminate that row

This is what I had done in excel 2007

```
Workbooks(1).Worksheets("duplicate_raw_sheet").Range(("$A$1:$R$65535"))._
 RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 6, 7, 8,9), Header:=xlYes
```

This is the macro added in excel 2007 vba to delete the duplicate entries. I'm just checking for the columns 1,2,6,7,8,9 and deleting the row using the above 2007 macro But  unfortunately It does not work on excel 2003 .

Now I need To implement it on 2003 .but this macro is not supported in excel 2003. Is there any code available to do these task? when I googled I found advanced filter = > unique records but that does not work I think so, because I need to check only 6 columns value but the advanced filter checks all columns. but I dont need that, becuase sometimes  the 6 columns may be equal and the other columns might not be equal and the advanced filter may not filter it into duplicate.

Please help me guys.. What the codes I have to follow or any other way to do it. Trying it from 2 days but not getting the way to solve it. Suggest me any method that takes effect or show me the path to follow I will do it on excel vba 2003 . Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Trying it from 2 days but not getting the way to solve it." Please show us what you tried.

Comment: What type of data is in the 6 columns you need to check? You might be able to concatenate the data into one helper column or use some other method to summarise the 6 columns into one cell. Removing duplicates would then just be a question of sorting the helper column and comparing adjacent rows

Comment: In 1 column I have a name and in the 2 column I have a  date and in the third column I have number  and remaining columns contains numbers

Comment: @jean I tried it using sorting and a formula to compare the 6 columns values but thats not efficient task becuase using 2007 remove duplicate macro i can delete duplicates  of 40000 entry data within 2 seconds

Comment: @jean and still the work is going wrong might be with the formulae I need some help from you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately, the feature you are using is only in 2007+.

So, you only care if the cells in columns 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9 are the same? I'm assuming that means you don't care if 10-20 were all the same.

With this assumption, here's an idea you can try:

Sort your entire range based on the first column.
Then, loop through each cell in the first column.
Check the value of the next cell. If the next cell is the same, then offset and check the value of the cell in the same row, but second column. If that matches, continue through all 6 columns. If they all match, delete the entire row.

So something like this (which you'll need to modify for your implementation)

```
Sub test()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim lastRow As Integer
  Dim rowsToDelete As New Collection
  Dim i As Integer
  lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row

  For Each rng In Range("A1:A9")
    For i = rng.row + 1 To lastRow
      If RowIsDuplicate(rng, i) Then _
        If NotExists(rowsToDelete, i) Then rowsToDelete.Add i
    Next i
  Next rng

  'now loop through the rowsToDelete collection and delete all of the rows

End Sub

Function RowIsDuplicate(source As Range, row As Integer) As Boolean

  RowIsDuplicate = False
  For n = 0 To 5
    'Offset(0, n) means, from the range, go down 0 rows and over n columns
    If source.Offset(0, n).Value <> Range("A" & row).Offset(0, n).Value Then _
      Exit Function
    If n = 5 Then RowIsDuplicate = True
  Next n

End Function

Function NotExists(col As Collection, i As Integer) As Boolean
  Dim v As Variant

  For Each v In col
    If v = i Then
      NotExists = False
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next v
  NotExists = True
End Function
```

I tested this with information in range A1:F9

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   5
1   6   5   4   9   87
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   6   5   4   9   87
1   2   3   4   5   5
1   2   3   4   5   5
1   2   3   4   5   5
1   2   3   4   5   5
```

I've got 6 duplicate rows in this table above. The code I posted caught them.

Its late, I'm tired... hope that helps.

Comment: with the number of rows/cells involved, this will be very slow.  Better to copy the cells values to a Variant array and itterate through that instead

Comment: Oh Dhang! I read 150 rows instead of 15000. Yes, I agree. Also, it would probably make the code look cleaner as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hii Justin and to the guys whom I asked the above question.Well I got an Idea when I kept on thinking about it.This is what I tried to do

Just use the Concatenate formula

```
 Cells(2,"T").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,F2,G2,H2,I2)" 'append all column values into one string then insert the formula till the end
 Range("T2").Copy Destination:=Range("T3:T39930") 'Apply formula to end of sheet
```

Now using the remove duplicates in a single column. You can delete the duplicated rows.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates_in_a_column()
Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = 39930 ' last row number say 39930
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("T1:T" & x), Range("T" & x).Text)>1 Then
        Range("T" & x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
MsgBox "Finished The Process"
End Sub
```

And its working.Well I think this is more promising way to approach because You dont need sorting or filtering techniques but one unused column. Any feed back please let me know